# Inequalities word problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, solution-verification

An analytical lab costs $3.50$ dollars to run a sample and has $8430$ dollars per week for overhead. If it charges $32.75$ dollars a sample, what is the minimum amount of samples run to reach a profit?

My solution:

$3.50x+8430=32.75x$

$32.75x-3.5x=8430$

$x=288.2$

The lab must run at least 289 samples.

Is this the standard approach or would there be a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: That's pretty much it.  Any other "approach" would likely just be a rephrasing or rearrangement of the same approach you used.

Comment: mmm.... I'd be concerned about language and *meaning*.  You say $32.75x + 8430 = 32.75x$.  But what *is* $x$?  If I run five samples and I *don't* make a profit does that mean the equation is still true. .... but if you *say* that $x$ is the number of samples where you break even then you are fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is great! Just one minor notation thing: If I were solving this, I would use an inequality instead of an equation. 
$$32.75x - 3.50x - 8430 > 0 $$
$$x > 288.205...$$

This makes it a little easier for others reading your work to understand what you're solving for :)